# PHP simple string encryption and decryption

Tags: php, encryption

Is there a simple function in PHP other than `mcrypt()` that can `encrypt` and `decrypt` a string.

I was trying out the code below, but that's too much for what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to encrypt page numbers that are sent with a URL, so users will not be able to access a page simply by making changes to the page number in the browsers location bar. My page number has some other data too, that I do not want visible to users.

Example:
`http://www.example.com/p10:05 to http://www.example.com/895f852d22d558esc23`

I don't need such high level encryption and decryption like in the code below. Just something that can do like in my example is sufficient.

Another reason I do not like using mcrypt, is because of the 2 `==` it adds to the end of a string.

```
$salt ='iodine';

    function simple_encrypt($text)
    {
        global $salt;
        return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
    }

    function simple_decrypt($text)
    {
        global $salt;
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, base64_decode($text), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)));
    }

    echo simple_encrypt('Hello')
```

Comment: In my opinion it's go big or go home. But I can see your point. Is the base64 encryption alone not enough?

Comment: The `==` is nothing to do with mcrypt, it's how base64 pads a string out to a multiple of 3 bytes.

Comment: @Matt base64 isn't an encryption, it's an encoding

Comment: yeah, sorry, i just saw that. My bad

Comment: try mcrypt and url_encode. That might work

Comment: One alternative would be to have a lookup table (an array in the user's session, or a permanent list in your DB) with completely random tokens mapped to whatever data you want. Instead of sending the user data they're not allowed to understand, just don't send that data at all.

Comment: @IMSoP I guess you mean "to a multiple of 4 characters".

Comment: @Matt For a shorter version, check my answer. URL-encoding of something that contains a lot of `+` and `/` characters may lead to a rather long string - sometimes. Probably something you want to avoid, especially since it would happen infrequently.

Comment: @owlstead We were both half right: the output is indeed in groups of 4 bytes, but the markers indicate padding of the *input* (groups of 3 bytes), which is why there is never a need for `===`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MCrypt does not add those `==` characters to the string, the base 64 encoding does. It is possible to simply remove them. Just make sure that the base64 string is a multiple of 4 characters by adding them back again when the string is received.

Base 64 can contain the '/' and '+' characters by default (depending on the input). [Replace them with URL safe `-` and `_` characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-7).

The code shows `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` which is *not* AES; it is Rijndael with a 256 bit block size. Using `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` - which *is* AES - would be better. This still allows the code to encrypt up to 16 character number values and it will decrease the output size.

There is no need to generate an IV if ECB mode is used, so remove that part of the method. There is no need to add unnecessary work for the system random number generator.

The `$salt` value is actually the key value, better name it as such to avoid confusion.

Comment: Does this solve your question? If so, please indicate by accepting or by indicating why it doesn't, of course.